# CIFS samba mount works from manual but not from fstab

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

hi I have a strange problem that I have been trying to troubleshoot. In Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I am trying to mount a samba share (NTFS usb drive attached to router) using cifs.
I can do this manually:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=admin //192.168.1.1/FritzBoxNAS/New_Volume /mnt/sambaHD/
```

and everything works well. I can go to /mnt/sambaHD and (sudo) create new folders, delete files/folder and all is good.

However, when I try to do the same from /etc/fstab, I can mount the share just fine (at any uid, gid, file_mode and dir_mode I wish) and go to /mnt/sambaHD and view thes files but thats it. I cannot create, delete files or folders (sudo or not). In fact when I try to create, for example, a folder I get:

```
lattepanda@lattepanda:/mnt/sambaHD$ sudo mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: No such file or directory
```

which is really weird. I have tried a lot of variations of the automount in fstab but nothing changes. My latest variation is:

```
//192.168.1.1/FritzBoxNAS/New_Volume/   /mnt/sambaHD cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/lattepanda/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1001,nofail 0 0
```

Can you please help? This is just too strange to figure out.

Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that the router where the usb drive is attached has a bad SMB implementation

Comment: Are you sure the implementation is `vers=3.0`? Unless you’ve experienced really sluggish write performance, it’s generally best to leave that blank so the initial handshake between the systems can work out which version they’ll use to communicate 